# Mininet-wifi custom topology

Tags: python, wifi, sdn, mininet, topology

At first I want wanted to create a complex topology (more switches connected to each other) but even this simple one is not working. I am not able to get a working connection eg. 'h1 ping h2'

Here is the topology:
[image: topology]

He is the script that should create the equivalent topology:

```
!/usr/bin/python

"""
Setting the position of Nodes (only for Stations and Access Points) and providing mobility.

"""

from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController, OVSKernelAP
from mininet.link import TCLink
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.log import setLogLevel

def topology():

    "Create a network."
    net = Mininet( controller=Controller, link=TCLink, accessPoint=OVSKernelAP )

    print "*** Creating nodes"
    h1 = net.addHost( 'h1', mac='00:00:00:00:00:01', ip='10.0.0.1/8' )
    h2 = net.addHost( 'h2', mac='00:00:00:00:00:11', ip='10.0.1.1/8' )

    sta1 = net.addStation( 'sta1', mac='00:00:00:00:00:02', ip='10.0.0.2/8', position='50,50,0' )
    sta2 = net.addStation( 'sta2', mac='00:00:00:00:00:03', ip='10.0.0.3/8', position='40,50,0')
    sta3 = net.addStation( 'sta3', mac='00:00:00:00:00:04', ip='10.0.0.4/8', position='20,50,0' )

    ap1 = net.addAccessPoint( 'ap1', ssid= 'new-ssid', mode= 'g', channel= '5', position='25,50,0', range='35' )
    ap2 = net.addAccessPoint( 'ap2', ssid= 'new-ssid', mode= 'g', channel= '5', position='75,50,0', range='35' )

    c1 = net.addController( 'c1' )

    s1 = net.addSwitch('s1')

    #net.runAlternativeModule('../module/mac80211_hwsim.ko')

    print "*** Configuring wifi nodes"
    net.configureWifiNodes()

    print "*** Associating and Creating links"

    net.addLink(ap1, s1)
    net.addLink(ap2, s1)
    net.addLink(s1, c1)
    #net.addLink(ap1, ap2)

    net.addLink(s1, h1)
    net.addLink(s1, h2)

    net.addLink(ap1, sta1)
    net.addLink(ap1, sta2)
    net.addLink(ap1, sta3)

    print "*** Starting network"
    net.build()
    c1.start()
    ap1.start( [c1] )
    ap2.start( [c1] )

    """uncomment to plot graph"""
    net.plotGraph(max_x=100, max_y=100)

    net.startMobility(startTime=0)
    net.mobility(sta1, 'start', time=1, position='0.0,50.0,0.0')
    net.mobility(sta1, 'stop', time=30, position='100.0,50.0,0.0')
    net.stopMobility(stopTime=31)

    print "*** Running CLI"
    CLI( net )

    print "*** Stopping network"
    net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel( 'info' )
    topology()
```

As already said, I am not able to even ping h1 and h2 :(
I even tried to use RemoteController but got the same result.
Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please consider the changes below:**

```
from mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController, OVSKernelAP, OVSSwitch
net = Mininet( controller=Controller, link=TCLink, accessPoint=OVSKernelAP, switch=OVSSwitch )
c1 = net.addController( 'c1', controller=Controller )
s3 = net.addSwitch('s3')
```

**Remove:**
`net.addLink(s1, c1)`

**Add:**
`s3.start( [c1] )`

Please note that if you set both ap and switch with the same ID (e.g. s1, ap1), they will have the same DPID by default. So, I had to rename s1 to s3. On the other hand you may define the DPID as a parameter when you add the node whether you want.